# Can a synchronized block with a future cause a deadlock

Tags: scala

Say I do the following:

```
def foo: Future[Int] = ...

var cache: Option[Int] = None

def getValue: Future[Int] = synchronized {
    cache match {
        case Some(value) => Future(value)
        case None =>
            foo.map { value =>
                cache = Some(value)
                value
            }
    }
}
```

Is there a risk of deadlock with the above code? Or can I assume that the synchronzied block applies even within the future map block?

Answer (score 1):

For a deadlock to exist, at least two different lock operations are to be called (in a possibly out of order sequence).

From what you show here (but we do not see what the foo implementation is), this is not the case. Only one lock exist and it is reentrant (if you try to enter twice on the same `syncrhronized` block from the same thread, you won't lock yourself out).

Therefore, no deadlock is possible from the code you've shown.

Still, I question this design. Maybe it is a simplification of your actual code, but from what I understand, you have

1. A function that can generate a int
2. You want to call this function only once and cache its result

I'd simplify your implementation greatly if that's the case :

```
def expensiveComputation: Int = ???
val foo = Future { expensiveComputation() }
def getValue: Future[Int] = foo
```

You'd have a single call to `expensiveComputation` (per instance of your enclosing object), and a synchronized cache on its return value, because Future is in and of itself a concurrency-safe construct.

Answer (score 1):

Note that `Future` itself functions as a cache (see GPI's answer).  However, GPI's answer isn't quite equivalent to your code: your code will only cache a successful value and will retry, while if the initial call to `expensiveComputation` in GPI's answer fails, `getValue` will always fail.

This however, gives us retry until successful:

```
def foo: Future[Int] = ???
private def retryFoo(): Future[Int] = foo.recoverWith{ case _ => retryFoo() }
lazy val getValue: Future[Int] = retryFoo()
```

In general, anything related to `Future`s which is asynchronous will not respect the `synchronized` block, unless you happen to `Await` on the asynchronous part within the `synchronized` block (which kind of defeats the point).  In your case, it's absolutely possible for the following sequence (among many others) to occur:

- Initial state: `cache = None`
- Thread A calls `getValue`, obtains lock
- Thread A pattern matches to None, calls `foo` to get a `Future[Int]` (`fA0`), schedules a callback to run in some thread B on `fA0`'s successful completion (`fA1`)
- Thread A releases lock
- Thread A returns `fA1`
- Thread C calls `getValue`, obtains lock
- Thread C patter matches to None, calls `foo` to get a `Future[Int]` (`fC0`), schedules a callback to run in some thread D on `fC0`'s successful completion (`fC1`)
- `fA0` completes successfully with value `42`
- Thread B runs callback on `fA0`, sets `cache = Some(42)`, completes successfully with value `42`
- Thread C releases lock
- Thread C returns `fC1`
- `fC1` completes successfull with value `7`
- Thread D runs callback on `fC0`, sets `cache = Some(7)`, completes successfully with value `7`

The code above can't deadlock, but there's no guarantee that `foo` will successfully complete exactly once (it could successfully complete arbitrarily many times), nor is there any guarantee as to which particular value of `foo` will be returned by a given call to `getValue`.

EDIT to add: You could also replace

```
cache = Some(value)
value
```

with

```
cache.synchronized { cache = cache.orElse(Some(value)) }
cache.get
```

Which would prevent `cache` from being assigned to multiple times (i.e. it would always contain the `value` returned by the first `map` callback to execute on a future returned by `foo`).  It probably still wouldn't deadlock (I find that if I have to reason about a deadlock, my time is probably better spent reasoning about a better abstraction), but is this elaborate/verbose machinery better than just using a retry-on-failure `Future` as a cache?

Answer (score 0):

No, but `synchronized` isn't actually doing much here. `getValue` returns *almost immediately* with a `Future` (which may or may not be completed yet), so the lock on `getValue` is extremely short-lived. It does not wait for `foo.map` to evaluate before releasing the lock, because that is executed only after `foo` is completed, which will almost certainly happen after `getValue` returns.